# Remove item using LiveData and ViewModel causes re-emitting

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I have a fragment showing a list of items, observing from view model (from a http service, they are not persisted in database). Now, I need to delete one of those items. I have a delete result live data so the view can observe when an item has been deleted.

**Fragment**

```
fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    viewModel.deleteItemLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        when (it.status) {
            Result.Status.ERROR -> showDeletingError()
            Result.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                itemsAdapter.remove(it.value)
                commentsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(it.value)
            }
        }
    }

}

fun deleteItem(itemId: String, itemIndex: Int) = lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.deleteItem(itemId, itemIndex) 
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
val deleteItemLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result<Int>>()

suspend fun deleteItem(itemId: String, itemIndex: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val result = service.deleteItem(itemId)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (result.success) {
            deleteItemLiveData.value = Result.success(itemIndex)
        } else {
            deleteItemLiveData.value = Result.error()
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine, but the problem comes when I navigate to another fragment and go back again. `deleteItemLIveData` is emitted again with the last `Result`, so fragment tries to remove again the item from the adapter, and it crashes.

How con I solve this?

Comment: Why does the fragment retrieve a stale list of items when it loads? Why doesn't it get an updated list?

Comment: I could do that. But in that case I'd have the same problem. How can view observe the delete result to, for instance, show an error message without re-show it each time it is resumed?

Comment: This is an architectural issue, you are trying to remove the deleted item from the adapter rather than listening to an updated list of items that reacts to the deletion.

Comment: I understand you. But imagine that I listen for an updated list instead of remove the item from the adapter. In that case, I insist, how can view observe the deletion result to, in case of failure, show an error in the screen?

Comment: I've added an answer explaining how I would approach this. With regards to errors this shouldn't be combined with the data in the repository, just a visual display to the user is enough at the time of deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than deleting an individual item from the adapter, it would make sense to update the original source of LiveData<List> since the view observes that list.

The item repository should handle deletions, removing that item from the LiveData<List> which in turns propagates the update to the view and then the adapter.

Repo might look something like this...

```
fun deleteItem(item: Item): Result {
    val updated = items.value
    updated.remove(item)
    items.postValue(updated)
    . . .
    // propagate result of success/failure back to the view
}

fun observeItems() = items
```

In your fragment you would get immediate updates from a single LiveData source

```
fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel.observeItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
             itemsAdapter.update(it) //use DiffUtil to update list or notifyDataSetChanged
        }
    }
}
```

Showing errors should be contextual, a toast message or some visual notification.

**Update:**
Handle error in deletion might look like this, off the top of my head...

```
suspend fun deleteItem(itemId: String, itemIndex: Int): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val result = service.deleteItem(itemId)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (result.success) {
            // push updated list to items
            val updated = items.value
            updated.remove(item)
            items.postValue(updated)
            Result.Success()
        } else {
            Result.error()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would be the view notified when an error occurs while deleting?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a generic Result returned as a concept, you could map it to yours and observe the operation from the view, Or have a LiveData<Error> stream that your view observes, its up to you. But I strongly advocate a single observer for the list of items. A single source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I changed my code so fragment observes from `onCreate` method instead of `onViewCreated`. And I changed the owner as well. Instead of `viewLifecycleOwner` now is `this`. This way, value is not re-emitted when fragment is resumed, but just when is created or `viewModel.deleteItem` is called specifically.

It is working properly now. If anybody considers this a bad solution, please, tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem when you use `LiveData` for events that should happen only one time. There are several solutions explained [here](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8) and [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150). They either wrap the emitted data or the observers. In this wrapper they store a flag that tracks whether or not the event has been handled/emitted yet.